# Binomial expansion derivative limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Can someone help me with this? I am supposed to use a binomial expansion to calculate $\sqrt x$ directly from the limit definition of a derivative.

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in the kind of language that is suitable for assigning homework.  It can lead people to suspect that you're copying a question without understanding it rather than expressing a question that is actually in your mind.  If you don't understand the question, you can ask for help with that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I am actually looking for some help with it. I guess from now on I will be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to calculate $\sqrt{x}$? Or do you want to compute its derivative? The wording in your question is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the derivative
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$
Here $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}h$$
Rationalize:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}h \cdot \frac {\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$$
And the rest should be straightforward...

Answer (score 1):

I remain uncertain what is meant by "use a binomial expansion".  There is a binomial expansion of $\sqrt x = \sqrt{1+(x-1)}$ in powers of $x-1$, and that is an infinite series, but you wouldn't be using the definition of "derivative" directly if you did that.  Perhaps the expansion of the product of two sums in the answer posted by "ImATurtle" can be considered a "binomial expansion" since it's an expansion of the product of two binomials.

Here's a similar method:
\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} \sqrt x & = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta \sqrt x}{\Delta x} = \lim_{w\to x} \frac{\sqrt w - \sqrt x}{w - x} = \lim_{w\to x} \frac{\sqrt w - \sqrt x}{(\sqrt w - \sqrt x)(\sqrt w + \sqrt x)} \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{w\to x} \frac 1 {\sqrt w + \sqrt x} = \frac 1 {\sqrt x + \sqrt x}.
\end{align}